# ImportJSON.gs parse nested JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm using the ImportJSON library in Google Sheets to parse JSON files. I have come across a very weird looking JSON doc that I am unsure about how to parse it. The JSON doc looks like this:

```
{
  "draw": 2,
  "recordsTotal": "80129",
  "recordsFiltered": "3988",
  "data": [
    [
      "28/08/2020",
      "US DOLLAR",
      "108.2221",
      "108.1224",
      "108.3218"
    ],
    [
      "27/08/2020",
      "US DOLLAR",
      "108.1529",
      "108.0529",
      "108.2529"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I am interested in getting the 0th index under `/data` and the third item in that list (`108.2221`).

Using a query of /data/0 in the function returns `#REF`

How can this be achieved in Google Spreadsheets using this lib?

Comment: Is that the value you are getting back ? Can you please share a copy of your sheet or a screenshot of the output you are getting ?

Comment: The json shared above in the input. Its is what's on the URL that I am trying to read. Using a query of /data/0 gives #REF

Comment: Could you share the URL with us please ?

Comment: URL: https://www.centralbank.go.ke/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_wdtable&table_id=32

Comment: I posted an alternative solution. Please check and let me know if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

You can instead create your own **custom function**:

```
function myCustomFunction(url,pos) {
  
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const arr =JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return  arr['data'][0][pos-1];
}
```

and use it again as a formula.

- For example, to get the **1st** element:

  ```
  =myCustomFunction("https://www.centralbank.go.ke/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_wdtable&table_id=32",1)
  ```
- or **3rd** element:

  ```
  =myCustomFunction("https://www.centralbank.go.ke/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_wdtable&table_id=32",3)
  ```

---

### Output:

[image: example]

---

### Limitations:

1. You can't pass any `url` as an argument. The json url needs to have
   the structure you mentioned in the question.
2. This formula only works for the `data` field.

---

### References:

- [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch)
- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [Custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: This works. So I have accepted it as it well answers my question. I am just realizing now that I had used a wrong payload I had filtered for US data). I will try and get the script to look up US DOLLAR from the returned JSON file and get pos-1 where pos=3 :-)

Thanks